# MongoDB is not distributing reads in a replica set

Tags: mongodb

We have three servers in a replica set. For the sake of example, ServerA is primary, while ServerB and ServerC are secondaries. While stress testing the environment, the server load on ServerA has spiked to around 4.00, while the secondaries remain at 0.00. The URL targets of the stress testing do not do any writes to mongo, but it appears that reads are not being distributed to the secondaries.

We are using the official C# driver.

ServerA log shows many connections being opened, lsn set entries, and a bunch of "killcursors" commands -- it is obviously working to serve up pages. ServerB and ServerC, however, only show the initial connections from the web servers (four of them), and after that only "lsn set" entries appear in the logs. After a few minutes, the initial four connections timeout and close.

The replica set is in full working order. I can stop mongo on the primary, and the secondaries will correctly elect a new primary.

Our connection string from Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="wellness.mongodb" connectionString="mongodb://serverA:27017,serverB:27017,serverC:27017/mydatabase?safe=true;replicaset=myreplicaset;slaveok=true" />
</connectionStrings>
```

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: What version exactly of the official C# driver are you using?

Comment: do you have to specify slaveOK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string looks OK. I'll try and reproduce and report back.

Comment: If you were using the latest version of the C# driver from the master branch on github, I found a bug that was causing all reads to be sent to the same server. The fix has been pushed to github. If you were using the v1.0 release then I need to investigate further.

Comment: We were using the v1.0 release, but we'll try out the latest version from github. I'll follow up with you shortly.

Comment: When I tested with the v1.0 driver I was seeing reads distributed across the secondaries correctly. It was only when using the latest driver source from github that there was a bug (now fixed).

Comment: If reads are being distributed with the v1.0 driver, what is the best way to confirm this? Maybe I am misunderstanding the logs?

Comment: I confirmed it two ways: I set a breakpoint in the driver where the read occurs and checked which server the read was going to. In my case I had two secondaries so the reads were alternating between them. I also started mongod with -vvvv flags so that it was echoing the queries to the console window and I saw the queries being echoed to the windows of both secondaries.

Comment: Thanks. While testing, are you using Connect() or RequestStart()?

Comment: The reason I ask is that I traced through the v1.0 code in github, and I thought line 695 in RequestStart was forcing those that used it (instead of Connect()) to disable slaveOk.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/0284f2fba29a64411058442723c3dc63811e65a1/Driver/Core/MongoServer.cs